# Is it possible to selectively limit an iframe's access to its parent document?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

**The Situation**

I have a static document (Document A), that I control, which contains an iframe that loads another document (Document B), that I do not control. Both documents are "owned" by me, and they are hosted from the same domain and in fact on the same server.

**My Question**

Can I restrict the access that document B has to the programming scope of document A?  I want expose some variables and functions of A to B, but without providing blanket access to the parent window, etc.

**Etc**

I know that via the **sandbox** attribute, I am able to make broad-brush sort of security restrictions with respect to parent window access, but what I'm looking for is a strategy for providing access for *some* javascript objects, but not others.  This is not a question about XSS or domain restriction.  As I've said, all of these files live on the same server, and the domain is not at issue.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends upon exactly what you want to allow and what you want to hide from the other frame.  You can hide much of your code and functions by putting it inside one giant closure.  Other code, even in the same origin cannot reach inside a closure to get to your code or variables.  You could then expose whatever functions/methods you want as global functions and those functions could provide whateve limited access to objects.

```
// closure to protect code from tampering
(function() {
    // code in here can't be messed with from outside the closure

    // this method can be called from the outside
    // This function (when called) can return objects from withing the closure 
    // or modify objects within the closure
    window.publicFunc1 = function() {
    };
})();
```

What you cannot do is control access to the DOM from this other frame.  If they're in the same origin, then it has full access to the DOM of the other frame.

If you control some of your infrastructure, you could create a subdomain that technically points to the same server and then you could load your page from the subdomain and the other frame from the main domain (or vice versa).  This would then give you real protection because of cross-origin protections and you could use messaging to communicate only in a controlled manner.